# Unix ps command producing unexpected extra line

Tags: linux, linux-mint

Under Linux Cinnamon Mint 21.2 the following command is producing an extra line of output:

```
ps -eo pid,ppid,args -q 229355
```

Here's the output:

```
    PID    PPID COMMAND
 229355    1696 /usr/lib/firefox/firefox
      5       2 [slub_flushwq]
```

The last line was unexpected.

The same command (ok, a different PID) on a Redhat Enterprise Linux system worked as expected.

Comment: Some basic research please. Examples: (1) Does this happen for any PID? or is `229355` is the only PID you observed that triggers the issue? Or randomly? (2) Does this happen even when no process with the specified PID exists at the time? (3) Is it always `PID=5` in the extra line? (4) Are results repeatable?

Comment: pedantic: `-e` is disabled by `-q`

Comment: According to the documentation `-p` should select pids, but it doesn't, so I used `-q` which does. On both RHEL & Linux Mint `-p` resulted in a list containing all PID's.

Comment: It happens with all PID's I've tried. Always. Yes, the spurious line is always with PID=5. It also happens when specifying a non-existent PID. But `-e` was the problem. Having removed that, the problem was resolved. It's a bug, but at least I have a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the `e` Option removed, it worked as needed.

```
ps -o pid,ppid,args -q 229355
```

Of course its a bug, `e` causing spurious output, but I have a workaround (solution).

And, without `e`, it works with `-p` as well:

```
ps -o pid,ppid,args -p 235219
```